# How can I get the a tag inside a li using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

im coding a program to pull data from sites to ease my job at my company I need to get the contents of all "a" tags inside "li" tags ive tried it by finding all elements by their xpath but it yielded no result here's my code and output:

```
def getLinks(link):
    driver.get(link)
    for i in range(0,10):
        result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[{i}]/a")
        for r in result:
            print(r.text)
    # for result in results:
    # print(r)

    driver.close()
```

[image: trying to get the path of all a tags inside li tags here]

output should look like:

```
http://turkosb.com/presmetal-otomotiv.html
    for all li elements
```

but what I get is:

```
   Presmetal Otomotiv Yan San. A.Ş.
    Belirtilmemiş
    +90 224 484 30 30



ps: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[{i}]/a") this code refers to variable xpath's of all a elements inside li elements
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, copy the HTML from the HTML inspector, [edit] your question and format the code in a code block.

Comment: sorry I thought that screenshots would be more understandable

Comment: Code in screenshots is hard to read, and is impossible to copy and paste into an answer. People like me frequently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> in the browser to increase the font size (blame it on old eyes). Images become grainy and hard to read when zoomed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `href` attribute but trying `r.text` which return the Text of the Element.

Use `get_attribute()` to get the `href` of all `a` tags.

And try Relative xpath like below. (As per the screen shot)

```
//ul[@class='box-listing']/li/a
```

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='box-listing']/li/a") # Xpath to find all the `a` tags.
for option in options:
    print(option.get_attribute("href"))
```